# Typescript getting is not declared when creating a new model

Tags: angular, typescript

I am sure I am just being stupid here, but I have this model:

```
import { Brand } from './brand';
import { Plan } from './plan';
import { Venue } from './venue';

export class Subscription {
  id: number;
  brandId: number;
  planId: number;
  venueId: number;
  state: number;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  rolling: boolean;
  overridePlan: boolean;
  productCount: number;
  price: number;
  termsAgreed: boolean;

  brand?: Brand;
  plan?: Plan;
  venue?: Venue;

  get stateName(): string {
    switch (this.state) {
      case 0:
        return 'Reserved';
      case 1:
        return 'Pending';
      case 2:
        return 'Active';
      case 3:
        return 'Cancelled';
      case 4:
        return 'Expired';
      default:
        return 'Unknown';
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I use a **getter** to display the **stateName**.
The problem is, when I try to create a new model:

```
const model: Subscription = {
    id: 0,
    brandId: 0,
    planId: 0,
    venueId: 0,
    state: 0,
    startDate: '',
    endDate: '',
    rolling: true,
    overridePlan: false,
    termsAgreed: false,
    price: 0,
    productCount: 0,
};
```

It moans that I have not set a value for **stateName**. I would assume that because this is a **getter** it doesn't need setting?

Here is the error:

> Property 'stateName' is missing in type '{ id: number; brandId: number; planId: number; venueId: number; state: number; startDate: string; endDate: string; rolling: true; overridePlan: false; termsAgreed:
> false; price: number; productCount: number; }' but required in type 'Subscription'.

Do I really have to specify it?

Comment: For an object for actually "be" a class instance, you need to create it with `new`. As it is, you have a plain javascript object you are trying to assign, and that object is not an instance of the class and will not have any functions from the class prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not creating an instance of the Subscription object, and as such any getters or setters on that class will not be in your new instance.

We use `object.assign()` for this task. Roughly like this:

```
const model: Subscription = Object.assign(new Subscription(), {
    id: 0,
    brandId: 0,
    planId: 0,
    venueId: 0,
    state: 0,
    startDate: '',
    endDate: '',
    rolling: true,
    overridePlan: false,
    termsAgreed: false,
    price: 0,
    productCount: 0,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes in TypeScript exist in 2 namespaces: value and type. You where using the type signature of class above, wich is the same as if you had defined the following interface:

```
Subscription {
  id: number;
  brandId: number;
  planId: number;
  venueId: number;
  state: number;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  rolling: boolean;
  overridePlan: boolean;
  productCount: number;
  price: number;
  termsAgreed: boolean;

  brand?: Brand;
  plan?: Plan;
  venue?: Venue;

  stateName: string;
```

To get your case working you need to instantiate the class using the `new` keyword and then assign values to properties:

```
const model = new Subscription();
model.id = 0;
...
```